# Explicit Intent Errors while working with putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, parameter-passing

Consider the Application has three Activities namely A1,A2,A3:

A1 calls A2 with an value appended in it's Intent "value"

```
Intent i=new Intent(A1.this,A2.class);
i.putExtra("value",editTextVal); //editTextVal is got from an editText during Runtime
```

where A2 accepts the appended value from A1 and stores it in "sample":

```
sample=getIntent().getExtra().getString("value");
```

Now the control goes to A3 from A2 .i.e., A2 intents to A3 and now when A3 calls the Activity A2 there occurs an error because A2 has the `.getExtra()` which tries to get the appended data from the Intent where as the Intent used in A3 has no `.putExtra()` it's simply this,

```
Intent i3=new Intent(A3.this,A2.class);
```

So there occurs a run time error.. Help me fix this..

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: use it like Bundle b=getIntent().getExtra(); if(b!=null){ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move from A3 to A2 ,A2 activity searches for a Bundle Object but since you are not passing any values from A3 to A2 it gives null point exception 
One way you can stop this is set a flag (static variable) and assign it any value say 1 when you make a transition from A1 to A2 on your A2 activity check value of FLAG if FLAG==1 try to get Bundle object. Whenever you move from A2 make sure to change FLAG to some other value other than 1

```
      //Declare a Variable FLAG in A1 as 
      public static int FLAG;

      // For transition from A1 to A2
       Intent I =new Intent(A1.this,A2.class);
       I.putExtras("Key","Value");
       FLAG=1;
       startActivity(I);

       //on your A2 activity 
       if(A1.FLAG==1)
       {
          Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
          String Value=extras.getString("Key");
       }

        //When you make a transition to A3

       Intent i1=new Intent(A1.this,A2.class);
       A.FLAG=2;
       startAcitivy(i1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("value")) {
        sample=getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
    }

    /* while using sample check for null

     */
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sample)) {
        // use sample here
    }
```